# Why is await Task.Run needed when calling C# from Node.js via Edge.js?

Tags: c#, node.js, asynchronous, eye-tracking, edgejs

I have this sample `C#` code that connects to the EyeX engine of the Tobii EyeX eye tracking device, subscribes to a gaze data stream and writes the result to the console.

```
var eyeXHost = new EyeXHost();
var stream = eyeXHost.CreateGazePointDataStream(GazePointDataMode.LightlyFiltered);
eyeXHost.Start();
stream.Next += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Gaze point at ({0:0.0}, {1:0.0}) @{2:0}", e.X, e.Y, e.Timestamp);
Console.In.Read();
```

I'm calling this code from a Node.js script with the help of [Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge). I was able to get it to work but I found that I had to modify the code in ways that I don't fully understand.

```
var eyeXHost = new EyeXHost();
var stream = eyeXHost.CreateGazePointDataStream(GazePointDataMode.LightlyFiltered);
await Task.Run(() => eyeXHost.Start());
stream.Next += async (s, e) => {
  await onGazePoint(new GazePoint(e.X, e.Y, e.Timestamp));
};
```

Namely, I had to wrap `eyeXHost.Start()` in an `await Task.Run()` call. Otherwise, the thread seems to block and no gaze data is received. I also had to add `async await` to the stream event handler.

Why was it necessary to do this?

Comment: Is your console app immediately exiting after hooking up the `Next` event?

Comment: @Rob There's a `Console.In.Read()` after, added to code sample

Comment: One thing that `Task.Run` does is prevent any current `SynchronizationContext` from being picked up. Some components (e.g., [EAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx)) will capture the current `SynchronizationContext` when their operations start and use it to raise their events.